# Change of value to the converter Int64 in string Python

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, data-conversion, int64

I have a problem understanding what causes the date value to change when I convert.

I have the following value "19670619", type int64.
I need to convert to String and leave the date "06/19/1967".

I did it this way:

```
Op['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(Op['dt'], unit = 'ms')
Op['dt'] = Op['dt'].fillna(datetime(2200,12,31))
OP['dt'] = Op['dt'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

I have the result: 01/01/1970 which is different from the original date it entered.
Another way I tried was:

```
Op['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(Op['dt'], unit = 'm')
Op['dt'] = Op['dt'].fillna(datetime(2200,12,31))
OP['dt'] = Op['dt'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

And the result was: 27/05/2007, I can not understand why this happened even when reading the other conversion cases.
Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows.

```
Op['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(Op['dt'], format='%Y%m%d')
Op['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(Op['dt'], unit = 's')
Op['dt'] = Op['dt'].fillna(datetime(2200,12,31))
Op['dt'] = Op['dt'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.to_datetime(df["dt"]).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"dt" : [ "19670619"]})
df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"]).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
           dt
0  19/06/1967
```

Comment: Fui aplicar dessa forma e me retorno o erro "can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". Vi em uma pergunta para colocar "coerce=True", fiz isso e deu certo para aplicar na coluna "dt", porém o resultado das datas continuam alteradas, não estão com o valor que deveria retornar